# How to add a slideshow inside a node with Slick?

Tags: 8

I created a Content Type with an Image Field that could take multiples images.
I would like to display a slideshow of these images.
So for each node of this Content Type, I would have a different slideshow, directly inside the node.
On Drupal 7, there is the [Field Slideshow module](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_slideshow) that seems to do that, but I'm on Drupal 8.

So I installed [Slick Carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick) and [Slick Extras](https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_extras) so I can use the formatter called Slick Image for my multiple images field.
But there are many options and I can't find the correct ones to have the slideshow working.

Here are the options :

[image: Options for the field formatter Slick image]

Can anyone give me the right options ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from an incompatibility from the theme I use, Zircon, with Slick carousel.
The full explanation and the solution can be found here : https://www.drupal.org/node/2875173#comment-12075392

In brief, the solution is to comment the following lines in zircon.libraries.yml with the `#` sign :

```
# assets/includes/slick/slick/slick.js: {}
assets/includes/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js: {}
assets/includes/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js: {}
assets/includes/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js: {}
assets/js/slideshow.js: {}
# assets/js/carousel.js: {}
```

This file is in /themes/zircon/ folder